# Number of triplet

Tags: combinatorics

How many triplet $(a,b,c)$ in $Z_{100}$ for which 
$ (a+b) \bmod 100 =0,  a \neq 1, a\neq 2, a \neq (3+c) \bmod 100, c \neq 98, c \neq 97$?

I want to calculate theoretically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a$ there are $98$ choices, namely $0,3,4,\ldots,99$. In each of these cases $b$ is fixed by $b = 100 - a$. If $a = 0$, then there are $98$ choices for $c$, namely $0,1,2,\ldots,95,96,99$. If $a \neq 0$, then there are $97$ choices for $c$, it can be any number not equal to $97$, $98$ or $a-3$ (and these three are distinct). So the total number of triplets $(a,b,c)$ is $98 + 97 \cdot 97 = 9507$.